# My gas valve is inbetween two plasterboard walls how do I access it?

Tags: gas, valve, natural-gas

My gas valve is inbetween two plasterboard walls[image]
How should I access this valve to try to shut it off or maybe have a new valve installed? I've already cut the hole bigger to get my hand in there but don't want to create an even bigger hole but not sure what to do. One side has a water heater and I can't access the valve and this side is where the stove is and I'd like to get a new stove but I cant turn off this valve and maybe I need a new valve but I cant see the valve the way its positioned in the wall. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah thank you I didn't know everything was designed so badly until my stove broke and I pulled it back and saw all of this. It sounds like it would cost some money to do all of the fixes.

Comment: Yes, it will cost some. But gas explosions are not pretty. The gas pipe work might not actually cost all that much - partly depends on the condition of the pipes on the other side. The drywall repairs you can do yourself - no need to pay a plumber's rates for that work.